# Chef Client for Every Node?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

Pretty new to chef, please forgive my simple question. Everytime I use knife ec2 to spin up another instance, another client is created. Is this normal? Is there a way to share the same client?

```
knife ec2 server create -I ami-a6926dce -f t2.micro -N "Redis-Server" 
                        -x ubuntu -i ~/.ssh/key.pem -G AppSG -r "role[RedisServer]"
```

After executing this command, on my open chef server web GUI, i see Redis-Server under the Node and Client.

Shouldn't only a node be create?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's normal. The client is to be able to talk to the API (using certificate-based  authentication) and the node represents the configuration (based on the run list and attributes).

Comment: So you can have clients that are not nodes, like an admin workstation.

Comment: Yes, technically this is right. In fact, it was like this in older chef versions. Nowadays you should use "users" for the humans, not "clients".